# wxWidgets exception handling

Tags: c++, exception, wxwidgets

When unhandled exception is handled in wxWidgets application in Windows, program shows Abort-Retry-Ignore message produced by Widgets exception handler. I want to get normal unhandled exception behavior: program should terminate with standard Windows unhandled exception dialog. Can I prevent Widgets to catch unhanled exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

Override `wxApp::OnUnhandledException()` and simply call `throw` there.

Comment: Tried OnUnhandledException and OnExceptionInMainLoop, both attempts doesn't give desired behavior. OnUnhandledException is called only after Widgets exception doalog is shown. Throwing from OnExceptionInMainLoop just terminates the program without exception. In both cases, original exception context is lost.

Comment: Note, `OnUnhandledException` is only called after the Abort/Retry/Ignore dialog presented by the default implementation of `OnExceptionInMainLoop`

Answer (score 1):

In wxWidgets 3.0.8 (maybe earlier versions too) you can override [`wxApp::OnExceptionInMainLoop`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_app_console.html#aca806b41cf74fd6166e4fb2e2708e9bf).  (That is actually the documentation for AppConsole, I couldn't find documentation for App, but it works the same).

If you rethrow from inside that function you probably will get your desired behaviour.

The base class implementation of this function is the wxWidgets Abort/Retry/Ignore dialog.

Note: this is also the thing to do if you want to handle the exception in your own way and resume execution, e.g.:

```
// In your App class that derived from wxApp
virtual bool OnExceptionInMainLoop() override
{
    try { throw; }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, e.what(), "C++ Exception Caught", MB_OK);
    }
    return true;   // continue on. Return false to abort program
}
```